# Embed PDF File Hosted on Google Drive on Website

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

There is a team drive full of PDFs.

I have set up oauth2 and can successfully login users. They can then enter in a file Id and my site will return all of the metadata for that file.

However I cannot seem to embed this PDF file. In the metadata there are two urls:

- webContentLink
- webViewLink

I tried creating an iFrame with both links but neither work.

Is this even possible to do?

I am using JS to do all of this and I am requesting the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly scope.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*webContentLink* and the *embeddable link* have minor differences.

**webContentLink:**

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/PDF_DRIVE_ID/view?usp=drivesdk
```

**Embed URL:**

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/PDF_DRIVE_ID/preview
```

Right now, I haven't seen a direct API method to fetch the *embedabble link* but if you plan to do this by code, you can just manipulate the *webContentLink* so that it removes the `view?usp=drivesdk` part and replace it with `preview`.

Sample snippet:

```
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/PDF_DRIVE_ID/preview" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Works. But do you by chance know of any way to remove the controls? And perhaps reduce the padding around the pdf file.

Comment: Google no longer supports embed link? I'm getting this error: `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'getLayoutMap' on 'Keyboard': getLayoutMap() must be called from a top-level browsing context.`

Comment: This is not working in ChromeOS. Getting the same error in MacOS with current Chrome.
Any solution yet ?

Comment: This doesnot work if Google chrome blocks the third party cookies. Is there a way around?